# SQL query - limit based on subquery

Tags: mysql, limit

I'm trying to get the top half of entries whose flag field equals 1.  I tried using a variable to hold the limit value as in

```
set @v1:=(select ceil(count(*)/2) as top_half from my_table
where flagged=1);

select * from my_table where flagged=1 order by 21_day_probability limit @v1;
```

But this does not work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under `SELECT` Syntax:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using `?` placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Therefore `LIMIT` parameters can never be [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html).  Your options, as indicated above, are to use either:

1. prepared statements

   ```
   PREPARE stmt FROM '
     select * from my_table where flagged=1 order by 21_day_probability limit ?
   ';
   EXECUTE stmt USING @v1;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   ```
2. a parameter/local variable within a stored program:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE foo(_l INT)
     select * from my_table where flagged=1 order by 21_day_probability limit _l
   ;
   CALL foo(@v1);
   ```

Comment: OK now i need a way do do this without declaring a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: @user1893354: How do you mean?  Using the second method above, one could `CALL foo(123);`.

Comment: but you would still need to declare the @v1 variable, wouldn't you?

Comment: in the last line 'CALL foo(@v1)'. I assume @v1 would need to be declared in order to do this

Comment: @user1893354: See my previous comment - "*Using the second method above, one could `CALL foo(123);`*".

Comment: @user1893354: Crikey.  It's the number of records to which you want the results limited.  You can replace with any expression that suits your needs.  This is *extremely basic* programming 101.

Comment: right but when I replace '123' with my query whose result is the desired limit i.e. 'select ceil(count(*)/2) as top_half from my_table
where flagged=1', I get a syntax error